# NPGSQL Install Fails Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, nuget-package, npgsql

Running the Nuget Package Manager (client version 3.5.0.1996) for VS 2015 Community Edition to install Npgsql 2.3.4, I get the following error:

Failed to add reference. The package 'Npgsql' tried to add a framework reference to 'System.Collections' which was not 
found in the GAC. This is possibly a bug in the package.

Is it really a bug in the package, or something having to do with my edition of VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been verified and submitted as an issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1604. For now either use VS2017 or Npgsql 3.2.3, we'll fix this for 3.2.5.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in 3.2.4.1 available on [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/).